# Mysql select username by userId for each row of other table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table with forum topics.
Each row in that topics table has a column with starter_id
starter_id is the userId of a row in the user table

I want to select all rows in the topics table, and want to get the userdata from the topic starter.

So the starter_id column in the topics table is the userId of the topic starter.
In stead of getting the userId in eash result row, I want the username.

I hope you understand what I want.

**Edit**

Table *topics*

- id
- name
- starter_id

Table *users*

- id
- username

I want to select all topics.
When I do that, I get all rows from that table, but with starter_id in it.
I want to display the username which belongs to the starter_id in each row I select from *topics*.

Comment: Can you please post your table names and column names?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a join for this something as

```
select 
t.*,
u.username
from topics t
join user u on u.userId = t.starter_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are 'topics' with 'started_id' column and 'users' with 'id' column and 'username' column

then query should be like this:

```
select started_id, username
from topics join users on started_id = users.id
```